# How to pivot large amount of data

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm working with a table with the following format:
[image]

I would like to pivot it using:

```
user_product_rating = df.pivot_table(index='review/userId', columns='product/productId', values='review/score')
```

The problem is that there are 80k records in original df. Both Google Colab and my computer are running out of ram. Is there any efficient way to achieve the same results?

Edit: Data I'm using [Cell_Phones_&_Accessories.txt.gz](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Amazon-links.html). I can't time it, always crashes.

Comment: %timeit tests can be done on solutions if you can post a sample data  too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me there are two options right now:

1. They the type of the 'review/score' column is not integerer already, I would try to convert it to type int.
2. As you only have to run one operation in your pivot table, you can use `groupby`:

```
user_product_rating = df.groupby(['review/userID'])['product/productID'].mean()
```